# Implications of migrating an iOS app to App Thinning and Bitcode?

Tags: ios, bitcode, app-thinning

I'm trying to update a legacy application to take advantage of App Thinning and bitcode.

However since each device now has its own custom build I have two concerns on which I haven't been able to find any information online :

- How do I update my continuous integration scripts to produce device specific binaries  ?
- Won't having multiple device specific binaries increase the overall QA effort ? Because now you might have certain resources missing only in certain binaries because you used App Thinning for images. If you now support two operating systems , you now need to test 5 binaries on 2 OS so you have ten configurations to support. Is there a way to reduce the risks in this ?